# How do the eigenvalues of $(X^{T}X)$ help understand the amount of variability in prediction in regression?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In my courseware on an introduction into forecasting, we are given the formula for a $\alpha \%$ prediction interval being 
$$\mu \pm c_{\alpha}\hat{\sigma}\sqrt{1 + x_{0}(X^{T}X)^{-1}x_{0}}$$ for the point forecast $\hat{\mu} = x_{0}^{T}\hat{\beta}$.

The reasoning behind this prediction interval makes sense to me, however after it's definition it is simply stated with no explanation that "*the eigenvalues of $(X^{T}X)^{-1}$ are very important to help us understand the amount of variablity in prediction, and raise a point about the effect of multicollinearity on prediction*".

But I am not very strong in algebra, and after looking up the definition and use of eigenvalues I still fail to see how they would explain variability in a prediction.

Comment: Look up "singular values" or "Rayleigh quatients"

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I can sort of see how singular values are related, but am failing to draw any conclusions relating to my prediction interval.

Comment: What do we know about $x_0$? Is it of length $1$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes..

Comment: Then the largest the value the square root can take is $\sqrt{1+s_1(X^{-1})^2}$. $s_1(X^{-1})^2$ is the largest eigenvalue of $(X^TX)^{-1}$.

Comment: Ohhh, so the closer that it is to singular the large our prediction error becomes?

Comment: That's right.${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Cheers, thanks, that makes sense!